# Failed to invoke android SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have an application that is using the SQLite database, but on half of the android devices, it has a problem to invoke it, and I get this error.
Although I am using these lines:

```
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        SQLiteDatabase database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        databaseHelper.onCreate(database);
```

of code to initiate my database, still, I got this error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference`.
```

I would be so glad if you help me to tackle this problem.

---

The following codes are for my Database Helper class:
`
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "foods_database.db", null, 2);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("create table if not exists foods(sFoodName text, sUniteIndex text)");

}

public void deleteFoodsTable(SQLiteDatabase database){
    database.execSQL("drop table if exists foods");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}
```

}`

And these lines of code are for initiating the database helper and adding item to database:

```
                DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
                SQLiteDatabase database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                databaseHelper.onCreate(database);

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                for (int i = 0; i < foodsList.size() ; i++){
                    values.put("sFoodName" , foodsList.get(i).getFoodName());
                    values.put("sUniteIndex" , TextUtils.join("," , foodsList.get(i).getUnitesIndexArray()));

                    database.insert("foods" , null , values);

                }

                database.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize your database object inside of database class
like this:

```
public void createDB()
{
  DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

Then call this function inside of fragment like this

```
DBclass classobject = new DBclass(getActivity());
classobject.createDB();
```

i hope your error will be gone :)

Comment: currently, I'm using it but it doesn't help me.

Comment: these are for initiating the database:
`
                DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
                SQLiteDatabase database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                databaseHelper.onCreate(database);
`

Comment: you make seperate class for database?

Comment: create application class and initialize database inside of it like this 
public class DataClass extends Application { public void createDB()
{
  DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
} then call like this 
DataClass dataclass = new DataClass();
dataclass.createDB();

Comment: I updated my question please see the codes and post your comment

Comment: try this 
// Database version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
// Database name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = MyDatabase.db;

public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
}